# Laravel - Access Config value using a wildcard?

Tags: laravel

Let's say that I have a config file called templates.php

It stores a list of  types and items.

Now,  I know that in order to obtain a specific row I could just do `Config::get("list.type1.item1");`

```
<?php

return [
 'list' => [
    'type1' => [
        'item1' => [
            //
        ],
        'item2' => [
            //
        ],
        'item3' => [
            //
        ],
    ],
 ]
];
```

But the thing is that 'type1' is dynamic, so I need a way to get all elements that matches item name.

Something like this (wildcards are not supported, so it doesn't work)

```
Config::get("list.*.item1");
```

What's the fastest (okay, that doesn't actually matter, I just want to know if it can be done at all) possible way to  achieve this?

Comment: If **'list'** is not dynamic, but only it's children, can't you get it and loop to get the children you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to put your dynamic type on a variable let's says:

```
$type = 'type1';

config('services.' . $type . '.item1');
```

Comment: Sometimes I'm really dumb. Thank you